# Excel VBA runtime error 1004 only with names that begin with 'c'

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

That's right. If I change the 'C' in 'Chart_Series_W_Gain_AAPL' in the following code to any other letter the code works. Otherwise it throws an Error 1004 at the Series.Formula assignment. In fact, if I use any random name that begins with 'c' the code fails but not otherwise. I've tried closing Excel and reopening, but same issue. I came across this because I had been naming my chart series defined names beginning with the name of the chart, but then I decided that was confusing and I attempted to prepend defined name used as a chart series with "Chart_Series_". Pretty benign change, one would think.

```
    Dim objChartWGain As Chart
    Dim objSeries As Series

    Set objChartWGain = Charts("W Gain")
    Set objSeries = objChartWGain.SeriesCollection.NewSeries

    ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add "Chart_Series_W_Gain_AAPL", "=W_Gain_Data_Array(W_Gain_Data_Alloc,1,W_Gain_Data_GainLossCurr)"

    objSeries.Formula = "=SERIES(""AAPL"",,'ThomTrade-charts.xlsb'!Chart_Series_W_Gain_AAPL,1)"
```

Comment: Have you tried adding 2 extra sets of quotation marks?

Comment: @KevinD, do you mean around the defined name?

Comment: Yes, like this: `""Chart_Series_W_Gain_AAPL""` or even `""""Chart_Series_W_Gain_AAPL"""`.

Comment: @KevinD, just tried, same error.

Comment: Wow, weird. You don't have any kind of fuzzy search sql "LIKE" type of command in any of your other macros in this workbook do you? Anything searching for a specific letter in a string?

Comment: @KevinD, no, nothing like that. It's totally odd.

Comment: K I think I got it, try Chr(67) instead. Maybe like this `Chr(67)"hart_Series_W_Gain_AAPL"`

Comment: Error confirmed. This is indeed bizarre and unexpected.

Comment: Excel won't even allow me to manually set that Series formula in the formula bar. The `Chr(67)` option does not seem to be working for me, either.

Comment: @Charles, did you remove my new tags?

Answer (score 4):

MSDN indicates you can't use the letters "C" or "R" (upper/lower) as names. I think there is a bug relating to when this letter is the first letter in the Name is either R or C (or r or c) which I have replicated your error.

Try using the Name's address in a string concatenated to your formula, like so:

```
Sub ChtSeries()
Dim objChartWGain As Chart
Dim objSeries As Series
Dim nmAddress As String
Dim n As Name

Set objChartWGain = Charts("W Gain")

'Replace with your Name definition:'
Set n = ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add("Chart_Series_W_Gain_AAPL", Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2:A4"))

'Turn the Name's address in to a usable string:'
nmAddress = Replace(n.RefersTo, "=", vbNullString)

Set objSeries = objChartWGain.SeriesCollection(1)
objSeries.Formula = "=SERIES(""AAPL"",," & nmAddress & ",1)"

End Sub
```

Info from MSDN here:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/define-and-use-names-in-formulas-HA102749565.aspx#_Learn_about_syntax

> You cannot use the uppercase and lowercase characters "C", "c", "R",
>   or "r" as a defined name, because they are all used as a shorthand for
>   selecting a row or column for the currently selected cell when you
>   enter them in a Name or Go To text box.

Comment: Interesting. What version of Excel are you using because I get a syntax error if I try to `Set` a `Name` object from a call to `Names.Add`

Comment: I can set the series formula with the name beginning with 'c' manually through the UI if qualify it with the workbook name. In addition, the workbook name must be within single quotes, whether or not there are spaces in the name. So `'ThomTrade-charts.xlsb'!Chart_Series_W_Gain_AAPL` works through the UI but not programmatically.

Comment: I see what you're trying to do here. You're just cutting the defined name out of the picture. This doesn't work because, if you look at my posted code, I am not trying to refer to a range. The names I'm using are actually a function calls with specific parameters. The Series.Formula property does not accept function calls directly, only names.

Comment: then what I'd do is just call those functions from VBA rather than from the series formula, then set the `Series.Values` = to an array of values or a range variable, and you can set the `Series.Order` as well.

Comment: The `Series.Values` property has the same issue. I have a VBA `Function` that returns a 1000-element array. I could dump that array into a `Range` object, but there are many chart series and that would be messy. That's why I'm using names in the first place.

Comment: If you for example were to `Dim arrSrsVals() as Variant` and populate that array with the function(s), you should be able to `Set objSeries.Values = arrSrsVals` with no issues unless you've run in to some limitation on number of points in a series, but ~1000 should be well below any limit. As for the problem with "C"-named `Names`, that seems to be a bug in the VBA compiler. I'm able to create the series in the UI, but not able to refer to it in VBA. Same for Names beginning with letter "R".