# Modifying a Dynamic Name with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that links to several other spreadsheets to pull data that compiled into one sheet; I am tasked with modifying the sheet to graph this data. There is a row of 12 slots for each month in a person's report; if a person was working in a month then the month will be displayed in the appropriate slot. For the graph I have figured out to use a dynamic name range so that the number of months in the graph is equal the number of months present in the line; the only problem is that the start pointing changes based on what month a person started.

I am able to make a rather large nested if statement but that doesn't seem like a very good way to approach resolving my problem. Is there a way I can have a VBA script change the value of the dynamic name range or just modify the chart's value directly? If this isn't a viable option is there any other way to approach this problem other than a dynamic named range?

I can't change how this report sheet behaves as this is a spreadsheet related to work and that's how they want it to be for reporting reasons; I'm simply looking to add the graphing functionality.

EXAMPLES:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/zn6yt4l6kjvwq33/Example1.xlsx
https://www.dropbox.com/s/j88tgoik68s4lhx/Example2.xlsx

In the first example you see an example of the problem when you select "Second" from the dropbox next to Agent Name. It's including pointless data in the graph.

In the 2nd example I have resolved the problem by adding an if statement to the dynamic named ranges used in the chart; but as you can see to include 2 months it's now massive and to include all 12 it would be pretty much impossible. If I were to add a 3rd person who started in March they would also not work in the 2nd example.

Is there a way I can make it so the values in the Dynamic name range are changeable through VBA? Can I modify the chart's values directly using VBA? Is there a way to bypass this problem without even using VBA?

Thanks.

Comment: for me, it would help if you could show a screenshot or a sample of what the spreadsheet looks like.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm not 100% certain I've understood the problem, but this might at least help to get closer...)

Try defining three names, something like this:

```
start_month
data 
chart_data
```

Where `start_month` contains the number of the column that you want to be charted, `data` is all twelve columns of data, something like `=OFFSET($C$1,0,0,COUNT($A:$A),12)` and `chart_data` selects the column you want from the data, e.g. `=INDEX(data, , start_month)`

Now set your chart's series to `WorkbookName!chart_data`, using whatever your workbook's called. As the `start_month` value changes, so should the values displayed in the chart.

Comment: A recent question indicated a potential bug using names that begin with letter "c", unable to assign these names to a `Series.Values` in VBA. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16002425/excel-vba-runtime-error-1004-only-with-names-that-begin-with-c

Answer (score 0):

You can add or modify a `Name` in VBA like:

```
Dim nm As Name
Dim rng As Range

'Here, you could use a more complicated expression'
' to derive the proper address dynamically.'
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A25")

'Now, add a Name to the workbook:'
Set nm = ActiveWorkbook.Names.Add("My_Name", rng)
```

With some string functions/variables, you could derive/caclulate the range address in VBA.